# Export schema compare upgrade script to transact-sql with visual studio 2012 premium

Tags: visual-studio-2012, schema-compare

I have been blessed with Visual Studio 2012 Premium at work. One of the tasks I've been given is to do a schema compare between development and system test databases. This is all well and good, but when I generate the script to hand over to the migration team, I get this at the header:

---

```
/*
Deployment script for MyGloriousDatabase

This code was generated by a tool.
Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
the code is regenerated.
*/

GO
:setvar DatabaseName "MyGloriousDatabase"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "MyGloriousDatabase"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"

GO
:on error exit
GO
/*
Detect SQLCMD mode and disable script execution if SQLCMD mode is not supported.
To re-enable the script after enabling SQLCMD mode, execute the following:
SET NOEXEC OFF; 
*/
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
        SET NOEXEC ON;
    END

GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)];
...
```

---

Now, it is not difficult to trim this out and make it into an .sql script you can simply run in SSMS. But I have seen that previous versions of Visual Studio had an "Export to Transact-SQL" option. Is that option hidden in 2012? The best I can find is an option to comment out SQLCMD lines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not see an option to do this Visual Studio 2013 Premium either, however the generated scripts can be run in SSMS by turning on SQL Command Mode via the Query->SQLCMD Mode menu item in SSMS.

See: [sql-server-setvar-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684997/sql-server-setvar-error)