# Dynamic USE in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple script, launched from the SQL Server Management Studio,  which restore (locally) a backup.
As soon as the database is restored I need to perform some operation on it.

The only way I found is to exec the sql statement and prepend the database name, like so:

```
EXEC('USE ' + @dbRestoredName + ' A T-SQL STATEMENT;')
EXEC('USE ' + @dbRestoredName + ' ANOTHER T-SQL STATEMENT;')
```

It obviously works, and there's no problem with small statements, but I instead have some complicated statement which are hard to be transformed to string, so I would like to do this:

```
EXEC ('USE ' + @dbRestoredName);
A T-SQL STATEMENT;
ANOTHER T-SQL STATEMENT;
```

But the results of the above is that the USE is ineffective, if you are familiar with SQL SERVER Management Studio, the rest of the statements are being executed from the database where the script has been launched.

Comment: Do you need to achieve this in SSMS only?

Comment: you can use `:setvar` which might be similar to what you want to achieve [using this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30479063/4436237)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your script in SSMS, you could use SQLCMD Mode (Query menu) to script a variable for your database name.

```
:setvar database "dbRestoredName"
use $(database)
go
A T-SQL STATEMENT;
ANOTHER T-SQL STATEMENT;
```